# Managed Metadata: Source from Data List

Tags: managed-metadata, managed

In SPO/O365, I have a Data List containing two columns:

```
A                 B
-------------     -------------
Red               1
Blue              2
Green             3
```

I'd like the data of the Data List to be available for meta data entry, in such a way that a user is able to select a colour (column A) and the value of code (column B) will be used in further processing.

I know to set this up manually using a Managed Metadata column but I'd like to tie these two together in other way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best option here is to create a Lookup column, which does exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

[image]

Reference: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)